# (Well-known) poem request: the wonder/beauty of nature/world/universe

Tags: poetry

I'm looking for any well-known poem that talks about the beauty or wonder of nature, the world or the universe.

The beginning of《醉翁亭记》isn't a bad place to start.

> 环滁皆山也。其西南诸峰，林壑尤美，望之蔚然而深秀者，琅琊也。山行六七里，渐闻水声潺潺而泻出于两峰之间者，酿泉也。峰回路转，有亭翼然临于泉上者，醉翁亭也。作亭者谁？

I just fear that the whole 醉翁 part will detract from the allure of the natural world.

Any suggestions would be helpful, certainly as I don't have much of a grasp of what or wouldn't be "well-known."

Comment: Chinese poems are full of depictions of the beauty of nature

Comment: this is a prose rather than a poem. conventionally, an author will express his thoughts behind the beautiful nature they describe.

Comment: Prose works for me too

Comment: @user3306356 there is a school of poem called 山水田园诗. Famous poets include 王维 谢灵运 陶渊明 孟浩然

Comment: @Huang Feel free to leave an answer with anything specific that is considered "well known."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you'll enjoy this one:

```
独怜幽草涧边生，上有黄鹂深树鸣。
春潮带雨晚来急，野渡无人舟自横。
```

This well-known poem was written by 韦应物 in 唐 Dynasty, with the title of 滁州西涧 (the west ravine of 滁 prefecture).

By the way, I think it suits 《醉翁亭记》 well, because both places described by them are located in modern 滁州 city in 安徽 province.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, this is more of a diary of traveling rather than a poem. The poem follows certain rhyme. You can try "唐诗三百首" if you would like to learn the poem. Below would be a good example

[唐诗三百首](http://www.gushiwen.org/gushi/tangshi.aspx)

```
江雪

唐代：柳宗元

千山鸟飞绝，万径人踪灭。
孤舟蓑笠翁，独钓寒江雪
```